# Where do the characteristics of self-attention come into play in Linformer's proof that self-attention is low rank?

Tags: papers, transformer, proofs, linear-algebra, linformer

In Linformer's proof that self-attention is low rank in their [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.04768.pdf), I don't see how it doesn't generalize to every matrix. They don't utilize any specifics of self-attention (the entire proof feels like it's in equation 20 utilizing JL, and I do not see where characteristics of self-attention come into play).

What am I missing?

[image]